# QML force binding update that depend on C++ function

Tags: c++, qml

Is there any way to force a binding in QML to be updated?
I bound the state of a Component to a c++ function using a ComboBox.currentText as argument.

```
state: cpp.isInSet(combobox.currentText) ? "a" : "b";
```

As you can guess the c++ function just returns true if the given text is in a QSet.
Now this obviously works fine when currentText changes, but in the meantime i add or remove strings from the set.
I can emit a signal when this happens of course, but how could i tell the QML Component to update it's binding?

As a fast and dirty hack i just did:

```
property bool hack: true;
Connections { target: cpp; onSetChanged: {!hack; !hack;}
state: hack && cpp.isInSet(combobox.currentText) ? "a" : "b";
```

But there has to be a better way that im just too stupid to find in the docs.

Comment: Would it be possible to pass the set that lives in cpp to QML as an argument of the function? Something like `state: cpp.isInSet(cpp.mySet, combobox.currentText) ? "a" : "b";`

Comment: You mean "exposing" the QSet to QML with Q_Property macro? That would be even worse than my hack, thats why i asked if i can somehow force an update of the QML binding.

Comment: Right. Depending on the situation, this is a very clean solution. You would trigger the state update with a setXyPropertyChanged() signal of the set. But if that is not cool in your case, there will be some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way if your cpp object has "setChanged()" signal:

```
function checkState() {
    state = cpp.isInSet(combobox.currentText) ? "a" : "b"
}
Component.onCompleted: {
    cpp.setChanged.connect(checkState)
    combobox.onCurrentTextChanged.connect(checkState)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

In your `cpp`, add a property;

```
Q_PROPERTY(int generation READ generation NOTIFY generationChanged);
```

Which is just an int. Whenever you want to initiate change from C++, change this "generation" number;

```
++_generation;
emit generationChanged();
```

then in QML, depend on `gen`;

(example)

```
Item
{
   ...
    property int gen: cpp.generation;
    ...

    state: gen, (cpp.isInSet(combobox.currentText) ? "a" : "b");

}
```

using the javascript comma operator.